# ¿Cómo funciona componentWillUnmount?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un componente que renderiza condicionalmente otros componentes dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla. De hecho, esta basado en la siguiente respuesta de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46586783/6531393).

Sin embargo, no logro saber como funciona componentWillUnmount, se el [significado técnico](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46586783/6531393) dado por la documentación de React pero no logro entender en que momento se desmonta el componente. Añadí un `console.log` y no vi en ningún momento que se imprima, y además, lo quite y seguía funcionando correctamente.

¿Cómo funciona internamente `componentWillUnmount`? ¿En qué momento se indica que el componente deberá desmontarse?

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isDesktop: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.updateScreen();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateScreen);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateScreen);
  }

  updateScreen = () => {
    console.log('updateScreen', window.innerWidth);
    this.setState({
      isDesktop: window.innerWidth > 768
    })
  }

  render(){
    const isDesktop = this.state.isDesktop;
    if(isDesktop) {
      return <LoginDesktop />
    } else {
      return <LoginMobile />
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El metodo se llama automaticamente, no es como que puedas llamarlo directamente, y este se activa cuando el DOM del componente es removido, pero no si lo remueves directamente.

se llama cuando:

- en el root de la app llamas `[ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode][1]`
- cuando el padre del componente lo remueve

y esta bien usarlo para remover Intervals y EventListeners, en tu caso necesitarias meterlo dentro del componente `<LoginMobile />`.

Answer (score 0):

**componentWillUnmount**

Este método es llamado exactamente momentos antes de que el componente sea removido del render..

por ejemplo:

> tienes una condicional en el **render**:

```js
render() {
  if(this.state.renderButton) {
    return <MyButton />
  }
  else {
    return null
  }
}
```

cuando el estado `renderButton` cambie de verdadero a falso, el componente `MyButton` desaparecerá del `render`. Es acá donde se ejecuta el `componentWillUnmount`, justamente antes que sea removido, el componente `MyButton` ejecutará su metodo `componentWillUnmount`.